# how to dpkg and apt-get packages on CentOS?

Tags: apt-get, dpkg

I dont have both these packages on my system. I am not able to install any package due to same. Can anybody tell me how to install these without root access??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg` is the low level package tool of the Debian distribution (and derived distributions such as Ubuntu, Linux Mint and others).  It is used to install single Debian packages (files with the `.deb` extension).

`apt-get` is a higher-level (user facing) program used to retrieve and install Debian packages on Debian systems.  It does not work on CentOS, because CentOS uses a different package format (RPM) and cannot work with packages that were made for the Debian distribution.

Also, you can not install packages without root access (neither CentOS nor Debian packages).